# Trying to use Google Apps Script from one workbook to another with onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

See sample at bottom of post.

Now nearly bald :-(

I have pulled out most of my hair battling with this!

I am trying to copy from one workbook to another when I mark a checkbox as true.  The true/false flag (trigger) is in column L (12) in the first sheet and then copies the contents of column M (13) to the same column in the other workbook.  I have the sheet ID stored in a sheet in the source workbook, called 'Client Info' at cell B16.  I use that to try and open the target sheet.  Below is my code (that obviously doesn't work or I wouldn't be here).

```
function triggercopy(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SOA");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Client Info"); // for client sheet ID
  var client = sheet2.getRange('B16').getValue();
  console.log(client)
  var targetWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(client);
  var targetSheet = targetWorkbook.getSheetByName("SOA");
  if (sheet.getColumn() == 12 && sheet.getValue() === true) {
    var observation = sheet.offset(0, 1).getValue();
    targetSheet.getRange(sheet.getRow(), 13).setValue(observation);
  }
}
```

Any help VERY much appreciated!!!

TIA

==================================================================
OK I have created two sample sheets at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D8exSXT2xboK6MOt8bl21NcOwatiCo0hZH6YbSJ_S-s/edit#gid=0
and
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_bVFrZl2NLOIKx4gDYplFzfaZFCBrIL-9Rhk2nIaedc/edit#gid=0

What I need is to be able to edit column C in the SOURCE sheet, then tick the box in column B and have that tick (column B) and the comment (column C) moved over to the TARGET sheet.

My code is

```
function onEdit(e) {
/* This script is designed to copy data from one workbook to another.  
It opens the source sheet (A) and sets the name to sheet
It opens the sheet (B) that contains the linkId for the target sheet

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SOA");  // A
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Client Info"); // for client sheet ID
  var client = sheet2.getRange('B16').getValue();
  console.log(client) // works to this point
  var targetWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(client);  // B
  var targetSheet = targetWorkbook.getSheetByName("SOA");
  if (sheet.getColumn() == 2 && sheet.getValue() === "TRUE") {
    var observation = sheet.offset(0, 1).getValue();
    targetSheet.getRange(sheet.getRow(), 3).setValue(observation);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Bowow99

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result from your question, where does the error of `PS I get an error when it's run saying TypeError: target.getSheetByName is not a function` occur in your showing script? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: In addition to what @Tanaike said,  Can you please share a sample spreadsheet with your input and desired output, so that we can replicate your concern? Kindly remove sensitive information.

Comment: Sample sheet added in initial post

Comment: If this approach won't work then any ideas that might?  I want to keep processing to the minimum (it's a very busy sheet).  Thanks

Comment: It seems that the approach you want is not possible, are you okay with alternative ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are trying to do is having an error because on your `condition statement`:

```
 if (sheet.getColumn() == 12 && sheet.getValue() === true) {...
```

you are accessing the column on the sheet level instead of range level.
I have created these lines of code to access the range level:

```
var range = e.range
 var col = range.getColumn()
 var row =range.getRow()
```

which I used to modify your code like this:

```
function triggercopy(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SOA"); // source sheet
  var range = e.range
  var col = range.getColumn()
  var row = range.getRow()


  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Client Info"); // for client sheet ID
  var client = sheet2.getRange('B16').getValue();
  console.log(client)


  var targetWorkbook = SpreadsheetApp.openById(client);
  var targetSheet = targetWorkbook.getSheetByName("SOA");

  if (col == 2 && range.getValue() == true) {
    var observation = sheet.getRange("C" + row).getValue();
    targetSheet.getRange("C" + row).setValue(observation);
  }
}
```

**RESULT:**
[image]

Comment: If you want the range of columns `B:C` to be transferred to the target sheet you may change the code in the conditional statement like this: `var observation = sheet.getRange("B"+row+":C" + row).getValues();
    targetSheet.getRange("B"+row+":C" + row).setValues(observation);`

Comment: Fantastic.  Just what I needed.  Kudos